# How to upload image base64 in ckeditor5 with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, image, base64, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using ckeditor5 to make some rich text. I need almost all the functions that comes with the classic builder. When I try to insert some image I get "filerepository-no-upload-adapter" error.
This is my code:

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";

class RichText extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <CKEditor
        editor={ClassicEditor}
        data={this.props.initialData}
        onChange={(event, editor) => {
          this.props.handleFunction(editor.getData());
        }}
        config={{
          toolbar: [
            "undo",
            "redo",
            "|",
            "bold",
            "italic",
            "|",
            "link",
            "bulletedList",
            "imageUpload",
            "|",
          ],
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default RichText;
```

I saw in the documentation (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/images/image-upload/base64-upload-adapter.html) that I need to install another package("ckeditor5-upload") and add this:

```
import Base64UploadAdapter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/src/adapters/base64uploadadapter';

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        plugins: [ Base64UploadAdapter, /* ... */ ],
        toolbar: [ /* ... */ ]
    } )
    .then( /* ... */ )
    .catch( /* ... */ );
```

I try to insert the plugin in the config, but it won´t work, it says that I am duplicating the modules. I just need the base64 code to send to the database.
Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

with react/next Base64UploadAdapter or SimpleUploadAdapter wont work you can instead use custom plugin . here is a code for the same its basic structure add to it as required for your particular project :

```
function uploadAdapter(loader) {
  return {
    upload: () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const body = new FormData();
        loader.file.then((file) => {
          body.append("files", file);

          fetch(uploadEndpoint, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            },
            body: body
       
          })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((res) => { 
            // resolve();
            resolve({
              default: res.imageAddress,
            });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
      });
    });
    }
  };
 }

function uploadPlugin(editor) {
  editor.plugins.get("FileRepository").createUploadAdapter = (loader) => {
    return uploadAdapter(loader);
  };
}
```

on server code api to store image and in response send address of that image can use blobs too . send header with token if authorizatrion is required for accessing your api.